# If I flip a coin n times how many different combinations are there?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

For example if a coin is flipped 3 times I know how to calculate all the possible outcomes.
I don't understand how I reduce that count to only the combinations where the order doesn't matter.

I know there's 8 permutations but how do you reduce that count to 4? {HHH,TTT,HTT,THH}

I've tried thinking about the combinations formula with repetition, the product rule, the division rule.

Comment: If order doesn't matter, then you **only** need to know how many times you got say heads(or analogously tails cause *heads*+*tails*=number of toss). Of course you can choose this number to be from $0$ heads to be $3$ heads so you get $\binom{n+1}{1}=n+1.$

Comment: Phicar is referring to [combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition).

Comment: If order doesn't count, then just focus on the number of tails you can get: that can be anywhere from $0$ to $n$, so there are $n+1$ different outcomes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more illustration , lets assume that we indicate both heads and tails with stars such as $"*"$ , and we determine whether they are heads or tails according to their position in terms of a bar such as $"|"$ .Lets say that the stars which are on the left side of bar are representing the tails and the stars which are on the right side of bar are representing the heads.

Lets assume that $n=2$ where $n$ is the number of flipping ,so we have $2$ stars and one bar , the all possible outcomes are

- $**| = \text{2 tails}$
- $*|* = \text{1 tail and 1 head}$
- $|** = \text{2 heads}$

As you see , the whole matter is just arranging stars and the bar in a row with permutation with repetition , then each arrangement will give you each possible distributions of heads and tails.

Then , by the formula of permutation with repetition  , if there are $n$ objects (stars ) of one type  and there is only one object (bar) from another type , then their arrangements is $$\frac{(n+1)!}{n! 1!} =n+1$$

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot of sense. All the other answers did too. As an extension if I have 3 letters ABC and I want to find all the combinations again is the answer 10? I've used the 3 places with 2 bars  and the combinations with repetition formula. Also listed it out and I think it's correct.

Comment: @BenHarris you are welcome ! When we comes your extension , if you think all posible words using these $3$ letters , then answer is $3!=6$ , but if you think it like this main question , then the answer is $C(3+3-1,2)=C(5,2)=10$ ,yeah you are right !

Answer (score 0):

If you toss a coin $n$ times, the number of heads obtained can arrange from $0$ to $n$.  Since all of the remaining tosses must be tails (excluding unlikely events such as the coin standing on its edge), there are $n + 1$ possible outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier if you list the combinations in sequence according to how many tails there are:

$$ \{HHH, THH, TTH, TTT \}. $$

That is, start with all $H$s and then for each successive element of the set, change one $H$ to a $T$. When you finally have all $T$s you're done.

Note that this set shows $TTH$ where yours shows $HTT,$ but since order does not matter, these are the same combination.